# MSBuild Publish Transform Path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, msbuild, publish

I'm building a C# project via MSBuild in Jenkins. Everything compiles correctly but when I get to the portion for publishing I get the following error:

```
PreTransformWebConfig:
Found The following for Config tranformation:
Web.config, bin\Web.config, bin\Web.config
Creating directory "E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\".
Creating directory "E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Views\".
Creating directory "E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\bin\".
Copying Web.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config.
Copying E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\server\VisualizationManagerWebService\Web.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\bin\Web.config.
Copying E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\Web.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\original\bin\Web.config.
Copying E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\Web.Release.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\Web.config.
Copying E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\bin\Web.Release.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\bin\Web.config.
Skip copying E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\bin\Web.Release.config to obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\bin\Web.config, File obj\x86\Release\TransformWebConfig\assist\bin\Web.config is up to date
TransformWebConfigCore:
 Transforming Source File:     E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\server\VisualizationManagerWebService\Web.config;E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\Web.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1475,5): error : Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported. [E:\Jenkins\jobs\FB20HMISupporting\workspace\net\core\surface\SurfaceVisualizationManager\SurfaceVisualizationManager.csproj]
 Transformation failed
```

I've tried about everything I can think of to find where this target is defined. I believe the format problem is that it is trying to call 2 paths separated by a semicolon. One being from a previous project in the build order. Can anyone tell me where in Visual Studio this is defined?

Comment: Also, it seems to build fine in Visual Studio, it just occurs when I try to use Jenkins through MSBuild. These 2 transforms don't even appear in the output from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested. It was a build order issue. After removing the dependency on the second project earlier in the build, it worked fine.